# jquery '[target]' mean anything special?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking at a snippet of jquery code and wondered what, if anything, special `[target]` means in brackets below:

```
  try {
        $.each($('a:not([target])'), function(index, value) {
            resetToParent($(value));
        });
    } catch (e) {
    }
```

That `try` block is defined in a 375 line(!) function and is not part of a click or other handler, otherwise the use of `target` would make more sense.  It's simply being called 100 or so lines down the function as part of the normal flow.

Comment: That's easy: that selects all `<a>` tags that **don't have** the attribute `target`. For example: `<a href="#">a tag</a>` would be matched while `<a href="#" target="_blank">another tag</a>` won't be.

Comment: D'oh!  Of course.  I was distracted by the use of 'target' in its event-handler role and didn't even think straight.....thanks guys.

Comment: You're welcome, we're here to help you. But next time, try paying a little more of attention. Probably the `try` block distracted you as well. I understand it and I understand that no one knows everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That selector is telling jQuery to find all `<a>` tags that don't have the `target` attribute.

So it would match:

```
<a href="someurl.com">A link</a>
```

but not:

```
<a href="someurl.com" target="_blank">A link</a>
```